# WiFi randomly turning off "via hardware switch"

Tags: wireless, 12.10, wifi-hardware-switch

My network card uses a 'Realtek RTL8187B chipset'. The issue is, after about 30 minutes of working, the WiFi turns off, and dmesg says:

```
turned off via hardware switch
```

Turning the actual switch [off] and [on] again doesn't change anything, and `rfkill list all` shows the device as `Hard Blocked`.

If I do `rmmod rtl8187` and then `modprobe rtl8187`, dmesg shows:

```
rtl8187: wireless switch is on
ieee80211 phy1: eeprom reset timeout!, ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

The 'nm-applet' shows the device as not ready. Sometimes I manage to turn it up, by using `ifconfig wlan0 up`, sometimes it doesn't work. Sometimes the `iwlist scan` succeeds, sometimes it shows nothing and whenever I manage to connect, after about 30 minutes I'm back to square one.

If I'm particularly unlucky, the card doesn't start at all, and instead it spams my dmesg from the system start by `unable to enumerate usb device` messages. Everything seems to happen more or less randomly.

- Can it be a problem with my drivers; `rtl8187 3.2.0-29-generic` or is the card faulty?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the wireless drivers that you are using, and, as such, is off-topic on Ask Ubuntu.  You should instead report this bug to the driver maintainers.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` and see whether it solve the problem. Sometime wireless issue could be due to its power management feature. I have encountered some issue with the power management on.

To confirm whether power feature is on, you can do `sudo iwconfig` and you would see the power management status in the output.

Comment: Power management is off. Currently I can't reproduce anything, because the card apparently got scared of my post and is working flawlessly.